# What is Ve in mosfet

Tags: transistors, mosfet

In this curve that shows the operating regions of the mosfet

[image]
What is Ve that is written Vgs +Ve ??

Comment: Ve is the variable that does into Id = K/2 * W/L * Ve^2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is Ve that is written Vgs +Ve ??

The word "positive" is sometimes shortened to "+ve" so looking at your graph you slightly misread what you saw - it says "+ve" and not "+Ve".

So it actually implies `the gate source voltage (when positive)`.

Comment: Looks like we answered this at the same time! Yours is better though, +1.

Answer (score 5):

"+ve" is a shorthand form of writing "positive". Likewise, you sometimes see "-ve" for "negative".

Comment: I have never understood why that has become popular. The symbol "+" already means "plus" or "positive", depending on context. Writing "+ve" is like saying "positiveve", which is just as redundant as "ATM machine" or "PIN number".

Comment: @DaveTweed I think it's because writing \$V_{GS} +\$ has some ambiguity; is it meant to be \$V_{GS} + V_{something}\$? Still, there are probably better ways of doing it; this just happens to be the one that stuck.

Comment: That's why most people would write \$+V_{GS}\$, which reads as "positive \$V_{GS}\$".

Comment: @DaveTweed In contrast to \$-V_{gs}\$, which could equally well mean "the additive inverse of \$V_{gs}\$", there's still potential for confusion. The quantity \$+V_{gs}\$ could itself be negative. This isn't exactly a problem to be solved in the comments, though.

Comment: No, yours is better +1 LOL