What is the history and meaning of letters “v” and “e” in expressions +ve and -ve?
Sometimes the longer form "\$15 \; \text {V +ve}\$" is used, instead of the simpler form "\$+15\; \text V\$". And similarly, "\$15 \; \text {V -ve}\$" is sometimes used instead of "\$-15 \; \text V\$".
I have 3 questions about it:

Historical: Who and when coined this longer form?
On meaning: What do the letters “v”, “e”, and the whole pair “ve” mean? They are probably abbreviations, but of what?
On usage: In which contexts is this longer form

common
at least acceptable
unacceptable?




Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/408914/what-is-ve-in-mosfet/

It's the "ve" at the end of "positive" and "negative". To indicate that "+ve" should be read as "positive", not "plus", and likewise "negative" for "-ve", not "minus".
What you call the "longer form" is pretty unusual. I would avoid it unless you have specific cause to use the terms "15 volts positive" and "15 volts negative", instead of the usual situation of putting the positive/negative at the beginning.

In 53 years in the industry I've never come across the "ve" notation.

After all, thanks to you, I know the meaning of "ve". :-)

@SteveSh I see it from time to time. It's more common as a scribal shorthand in handwritten notes than in typeset documents; a student's lecture notes might say "when V is +ve" when the professor said "when the voltage is positive".

AFAIK, it's most common as a British-ism, though I don't know the full scope of it. I don't think anyone here in the 'states uses it, or at least not more than a small minority? I don't recall seeing it used in professional or academic formats, either; my understanding is it's more informal. Like, you'll see it here from time to time, and on personal webpages, and often enough in forum posts etc., but not in formal media.

I use it. Maybe it's a Commonwealth thing.

Sounds like a question for [hsm.se] !

This American was familiar with these abbreviations.  Agree that they're informal.  And pointless, since they take just as much space as "< 0" or "> 0" (and provides no option to avoid ambiguity between strict "> 0" vs inclusive "≥ 0")

@SteveSh, I've seen it in posts in this site, not even in drawings, but in the middle of English text too. It was confusing at first, and appeared incredibly lazy after I got the meaning.

Before computers (and the IBM Golfball), manuals were typeset. Standard typewriters did not have > and < symbols, and many voltages were variable under load. Without the 15 for accuracy, and > or < for range, +ve and -ve were sufficient, and also distinct from the English words. I'm positive that these have no negative connotations.
